# How to convert the nested for loop in apply function

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply, sapply

Here I've nested loop i don't know how to convert this into apply can anyone tell me how to convert this in to apply function

```
    plans_achievements <- function(pa_m,pa_q){
             if(nrow(pa_m)==0 & nrow(pa_q==0)){
                df = data.frame(a = c(""), b = c("No Data Available"))
                colnames(df)=""
              }else{
                pa_m= pa_m%>% select(inc,month_year,Plans,Achievements,quarter_year)
                colnames(pa_mon)[2] = "Period"
        
        pa_q= pa_q%>% select(inc,quarter_year,Plans,Achievements)
        colnames(pa_qtr)[2] = "Period"
        
        df = data.frame(inc=c(""),Period=c(""),Plans=c(""),Achievements=c(""))
        
        for (q in unique(pa_q$Period)){
          df1 = pa_q[pa_q$Period==q,]
          df1$Period = paste0("<span style=\"color:#288D55\">",df1$Period,"</span>")
          df1$Plans = paste0("<span style=\"color:#288D55\">",df1$Plans,"</span>")
          df1$Achievements = paste0("<span style=\"color:#288D55\">",df1$Achievements,"</span>")
          df = rbind(df,df1)
          for (m in unique(pa_m$quarter_year)){
            if(m==q){
              df2 = pa_m[pa_m$quarter_year==q,][-5]
              df = rbind(df,df2)
            }
          }
        }
        df = df[-1,]
      }
    
          return(df)
        }
```

DT::datatable(plans_achievements(pa_m[pa_m$inc=="vate",],pa_q[pa_q$inc=="vate",]), rownames = F,escape = FALSE,selection=list(mode="single",target="row"),options = list(pageLength = 50,scrollX = TRUE,dom = 'tp',ordering=F,columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(0)),list(className = 'dt-left', targets = '_all'))))

Comment: it would help a lot for you to give an example of your input and expected output.  from your code it is not necessarily an `apply` function that you need here.

Comment: Does `df = rbind(df,df2)` work? `rbind` errors for me when trying to bind tables of different column names

Comment: @GeorgeSavva i updated the code with sample data and actual function

Comment: @JonnyPhelps use the edited code to avoid the errors

Answer (score 0):

I could not imagine why you would want to do this, what about vectorizing the function instead?

Note a few typing errors (pa_mon instead of pa_m etc.) has been corrected below

```
plans_achievements2 <- function(pa_m,pa_q){
    if(nrow(pa_m)==0 & nrow(pa_q==0)){
      df = data.frame(a = c(""), b = c("No Data Available"))
      colnames(df)=""
    }else{
      pa_m= pa_m%>% select(inc,month_year,Plans,Achievements,quarter_year)
      colnames(pa_m)[2] = "Period"
      
      pa_q= pa_q%>% select(inc,quarter_year,Plans,Achievements)
      colnames(pa_q)[2] = "Period"
      df <- pa_q
      df$Period <- paste0("<span style=\"color:#288D55\">",df$Period,"</span>")
      df$Plans = paste0("<span style=\"color:#288D55\">",df$Plans,"</span>")
      df$Achievements = paste0("<span style=\"color:#288D55\">",df$Achievements,"</span>")
      return(rbind(df, pa_m[pa_m$quarter_year %in% pa_q$Period,-5])[-1, ])
    }
    return(df)
  }
```

Comment: For loop take so much of time to execute this function in my application so only i heard apply is more faster than for loop... unique(pa_q$Period) has four value according to the value the loop should iterate

Comment: It is a general misconception that is still sticking around. The `*apply` family are simply glorified "for-loops" that gain nothing in performance if the loop is properly implemented.  Whenever possible vectorizing is the way to go, where vectorizing describes using functions that have been optimized to take multiple inputs (such as `paste0` which can take `vector`s as input). In the above I've removed the for loop and utilized that all periods in `pa_q` are iterated over, and `paste0` can hande the arguments, meanwhile `pa_m` only needs the periods which are also present in `pa_q` eg `%in%`

Comment: Bi-comment: There are still good reasons to use `*apply` functions, as they can improve function readability. Here I'd use `dfs <- lapply(unique(pa_q$Period), \(x){function here})` and combine the result after the call using `do.call(rbind, dfs)`. This will never been vectorized functions. :-)

Comment: I tried @Oliver but i am getting some error so can you please edit the above code

Comment: No? I've used your example data above and executed `plans_achievements2(pa_m, pa_q)` (Note the **2**). This works without error on my end.

Comment: i tried to apply this on my code dfs <- lapply(unique(pa_q$Period), \(x){function here}) i am getting some error @oliver

Comment: why because there are four quarter, for q1 it will show apr,may jun, same for rest of the quarters but using plans_achievements2 it will combined the four quarter first then the data is showing according to the month and still i am facing errors while using the function in whole data because the iteration is needed